# VSS is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

I have shared a project using VSS, it's working now but after I check in from my computer and get latest from another computer I am not getting the latest updates instead I got the old version of file. I am also getting WebDev.Webserver error message, after some files in the solution takes too long to open and mostly not opening at the end.

Maybe I am mistaking in configuring the vss or users?

Comment: and i thought vss was dead a decade ago :P

Comment: :) Dear @Asdfg, it will be soon from my end also if I'll keep getting such problems in the future..........

Comment: It's better you take decision now before Microsoft takes decision to deprecate the support for this product. Why not using Git?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are already some local copies in your working folder. By getting latest version to working folder:

- If your local copy is read-only, VSS will just replace it with the server version.
- If your local copy is writable, the behavior of VSS depends on your client side's setting. Please check your setting at **Tools -> Options | Local Files tab -> Replace writable files**.

For the WebDev.Webserver error message, you may refer to [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsdebug/thread/2adbd3dc-b0cd-4915-8c86-fc2869e845d7).

Comment: Hi @Logan. thanks for your answer I just gone through the working folder but it doesn't contain any copies, but the main copy. But yes I have another copy of that project as a backup but it is unbind from VSS. I checked the  steps and Ask option is selected there...

Comment: Hi @AjendraPrasad, if that is not the case, the only suggestion from my side might be applying the [latest hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=291) to fix any possible bugs. But I gave up last year and migrated to a VSS replacement - SourceAnywhere Standalone. Good luck :)